# Implantación de soluciones de inteligencia artificial en salud (chatbot AI)

Tags: python

Cómo podría mejorar el preprocesamiento de texto en el chatbot para capturar de manera más efectiva las características importantes de las frases de entrada. Ya que al ejecutar y al hacer la preguntas para pedir una solicitud de una cita me salta el mensaje default "Lo siento, no entendí tu solicitud.". También cómo mejorar el rendimiento del modelo de chatbot mediante técnicas de entrenamiento más efectivas, cómo aumentar el tamaño y la diversidad del conjunto de datos de entrenamiento, especialmente con ejemplos de la clase "solicitud_cita". Intenté solucionarlo de varias maneras pero no doy con ello. Si alguien me puede ayudar.

archivo: chatbot.py

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from keras.models import load_model

# Cargar el modelo y los datos necesarios
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.load(open('intents.json'))
words = pickle.load(open('words.pkl', 'rb'))
classes = pickle.load(open('classes.pkl', 'rb'))
model = load_model('chatbot_model.h5')

# Funciones de procesamiento de texto mejoradas
def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    # Convertir texto a minúsculas
    sentence_words = [word.lower() for word in sentence_words]
    # Eliminar signos de puntuación
    sentence_words = [word for word in sentence_words if word.isalnum()]
    # Lemmatizar palabras
    sentence_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words

def bag_of_words(sentence):
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    bag = [0]*len(words)
    for w in sentence_words:
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word == w:
                bag[i]= 1
                break
    return np.array(bag)

# Función para predecir la clase de la intención
def predict_class(sentence):
    bow = bag_of_words(sentence)
    res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
    max_index = np.argmax(res)
    category = classes[max_index]
    return category

# Lógica para manejar la solicitud de cita médica
def handle_appointment_request():
    specialty = input("¿A qué especialidad médica desea acudir?: ")
    date = input("¿En qué fecha desea la cita? (Formato: DD/MM/AAAA): ")
    time = input("¿A qué hora? (Formato: HH:MM): ")
    appointment_ref = generate_random_ref()
    print("La cita ha sido programada con éxito.")
    print("Número de referencia de la cita:", appointment_ref)

# Lógica para manejar la confirmación de cita
def handle_appointment_confirmation():
    appointment_ref = input("Por favor, proporcione el número de referencia de la cita: ")
    print("La cita con el número de referencia", appointment_ref, "está confirmada.")

# Lógica para manejar la cancelación de cita
def handle_appointment_cancellation():
    appointment_ref = input("Por favor, proporcione el número de referencia de la cita que desea cancelar: ")
    print("La cita con el número de referencia", appointment_ref, "ha sido cancelada.")

# Generador de número de referencia aleatorio
def generate_random_ref():
    return ''.join(random.choices('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', k=6))

# Función principal de chatbot
def get_response(tag):
    list_of_intents = intents['intents']
    result = ""
    appointment_action = None  # Variable para almacenar la acción de la cita
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i["tag"] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            if tag == "solicitud_cita":
                appointment_action = "solicitud_cita"  
            elif tag == "confirmacion_cita":
                appointment_action = "confirmacion_cita"
            elif tag == "cancelacion_cita":
                appointment_action = "cancelacion_cita"
            break
    if not result:
        print("Lo siento, no entendí tu solicitud.")
    return result, appointment_action  # Devolver también la acción de la cita


# Bucle principal del chatbot
while True:
    message = input("")
    tag = predict_class(message)
    res, appointment_action = get_response(tag)
    print(res)
    if appointment_action:
        if appointment_action == "solicitud_cita":
            handle_appointment_request()
        elif appointment_action == "confirmacion_cita":
            handle_appointment_confirmation()
        elif appointment_action == "cancelacion_cita":
            handle_appointment_cancellation()
```

archivo: training.py

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD

# Inicializar el lematizador de NLTK
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

# Cargar las intenciones desde el archivo JSON
intents = json.load(open('intents.json'))

# Descargar recursos de NLTK si no están ya disponibles
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('omw-1.4')

# Inicializar listas para palabras, clases y documentos
words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['?', '!', '¿', '¡', '.', ',']

# Procesar las intenciones para construir el corpus de palabras y documentos
for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent["tag"]))
        if intent["tag"] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent["tag"])

# Lematizar y normalizar palabras, eliminar caracteres ignorados
words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))

# Guardar las palabras y clases en archivos pickle para su reutilización
pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(classes, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))

# Procesar los documentos para construir el conjunto de entrenamiento
training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)
for document in documents:
    bag = []
    word_patterns = document[0]
    word_patterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
    for word in words:
        bag.append(1) if word in word_patterns else bag.append(0)

    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])

# Dividir el conjunto de entrenamiento en características (train_x) y etiquetas (train_y)
train_x = np.array([i[0] for i in training])
train_y = np.array([i[1] for i in training])

# Definir arquitectura del modelo de red neuronal
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

# Compilar el modelo utilizando el optimizador SGD
sgd = SGD(learning_rate=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Entrenar el modelo con el conjunto de entrenamiento
train_process = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=1)

# Guardar el modelo entrenado en un archivo H5
model.save("chatbot_model.h5")
```

archivo: intents.json

```
{
    "intents": [
      {
        "tag": "solicitud_cita",
        "patterns": ["Quisiera programar una cita", "Necesito ver al médico", "¿Puedo reservar una cita?"],
        "responses": ["Claro, ¿para qué fecha desea programar la cita?", "Por supuesto, ¿en qué día y hora le gustaría la cita?"]
      },
      {
        "tag": "confirmacion_cita",
        "patterns": ["¿Mi cita para mañana está confirmada?", "Quisiera confirmar mi cita", "¿Recibieron mi solicitud de cita?"],
        "responses": ["Sí, su cita para mañana está confirmada.", "Su cita ha sido confirmada correctamente.", "Hemos recibido su solicitud de cita."]
      },
      {
        "tag": "cancelacion_cita",
        "patterns": ["Necesito cancelar mi cita", "¿Puedo cambiar mi cita?", "No podré asistir a mi cita"],
        "responses": ["Entendido, ¿podría proporcionar el número de su cita para cancelarla?", "Por supuesto, ¿cuál es el motivo de la cancelación?", "¿Podría confirmar su nombre y fecha de nacimiento para cancelar la cita?"]
      }
      
    ]
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]